# Why Data.Time.Clock provides DiffTime and NominalDiffTime?

Tags: datetime, haskell

What is the rationale behind providing `DiffTime` **and** `NominalDiffTime` in [Data.Time.Clock](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/libraries/time/Data-Time-Clock.html)?

Currently, I don't see the need for both.

Also, I don't understand why for `NominalDiffTime` there is `diffUTCTime`, while for `DiffTime` there is not such a function.

I mean, it looks like `DiffTime` and `NominalDiffTime` are not really 'symmetric' to each other.

Perhaps to sum it up: What is the difference between those algebraic datatypes?

Comment: `DiffTime` is an actual time period. `NominalDiffTime` may contain leap seconds or even leap hours (as I understand it).

Comment: I suspect the reason why there is no `diffUTCTime` for `DiffTime` is because there is in general no way to calculate the difference accurately for dates more than (a year?) in the future since leap seconds are unpredictable and they're only announced so far in advance.

Answer (score 11):

`NominalDiffTime` ignores leap-seconds and you can be sure that `diffUTCTime` between 23:00 UTC and 01:00 UTC of next day is always 2 hours, without any seconds added.

Result of `DiffTime` can be changed by other factors, for example, leap-seconds. This is measured as with stopwatch: if, for some reasons, between 23:00 UTC and 01:00 UTC is not 2 hours, this type will show it.

In practice, they did not differ.

**EDIT:** They have different objectives.

- `NominalDiffTime` is for calculating difference between the times.
- `DiffTime` is for measured time (with stopwatch, for example).

Comment: They do not differ *much* very *often* but they do differ sometimes, and sometimes that difference is important.

Comment: Hm, but how do I create a `DiffTime` that includes a leap seconds? I mean I can't just subtract UniversalTime 2012-06-30_23:00:00 from UnversalTime 2012-07-01_01:00:00 because there is no diffUniversalTime ... Or can I?

Comment: You can't, because DiffTime isn't for difference between times, it's for measured time (with stopwatch, for example).